# interesting question about strcat(s,t) copies the string t to the end of s

Tags: c, pointers

```c
void StrcatStr(char *s, char *t) {
    while (*s++ != '\0');
    while ((*s++ = *t++) != '\0');
}
```

```c
int main() {
    char str1[] = "abcd";
    char str2[] = "sss";
    StrcatStr(str1, str2);
    printf("%s", str1);
    return 0;
}
```

At first, I found pointer `s` point to the character `'a'`, but next it pointed invalid character in string. Finally, system told me stack around the variable  `str1` was corrupted. Why did this thing happen? Shouldn't the pointer `s` point to the character `'b'` next?

Comment: It does point to the character `b` next. I guess you clicked the "run this line and go to the next one" button in your debugger, and it did the whole loop at once because it's only one line?

Comment: After `while (*s++ != '\0');`, `s` will point *past* the null terminator of the first string, because of the post-increment. However, a larger issue is that you're writing out of bounds of `str1`.

Comment: It's not an interesting question, it's a plain old array out of bounds bug. You need to study arrays before studying strings, simple as that.

Comment: oh, thanks a lot. What you said is correct. 'while (*s++ != '\0');' only one line, so the while loop finished at once. i still need to learn many things about the relationship between array and pointer .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition

```
char str1[] = "abcd";
```

is equivalent to

```
char str1[5] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '\0' };
```

That means the array will have only five elements. And arrays are not dynamic and can't be extended after their definition.

So using this as a destination for any `strcat`-like function will write *out of bounds* and give you *undefined behavior*.

You need to make sure that the array have enough space in it to fit both strings, for example by setting an explicit size (that is known to be enough):

```
// 30 should be more than enough to fit two 4-character strings plus the terminator
char str1[30] = "abcd";
```

Comment: awesome, thank you very much. with your help, i finally realize array is static. so we can't copy the string at the end of  `str1`( **only have space for five elements**). it seems like my single room can't allow two people to live in it.

Comment: sorry,can i use the following code replace it?  `char *str1 = "abcd";
     char *str2 = "sss";`

Comment: @neilguo Literals strings in C have two properties: 1) They are really arrays of characters, so behind the curtains it's similar to `char literal_string_abcd[] = "abcd"; char *str1 = literal_string_abcd;` Then 2) Literal strings *can't be modified*. They are in essence *read-only*. Which is why it's recommended to use `const char *` for pointers to them, as in `const char *str1 = "abcd";`. So no, you can't use pointers to literal strings as a destination for any kind of string or character manipulation.

Comment: oh, i see!!! when we only use pointers to literal string constant. we can't modify it. Because it is put in the code area.but for array of characters, assuming by enlarging the index of array to ensure the stack static area don't be broken, we can write something into the array, for example, the array of character `char str1[30] = "abcd";`  right?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the first while, you should write *(++s) instead of *s++. With s++ you're actually giving in return the current value of s and then incrementing is value, what happens when you get to '\0'?
s -> '\0', the condition in the while loop is now false, but you're still incrementing the value!! So you're not pointing to the '\0' character, but to 1 char ahead of it. With you're second while you modify bytes out of the string, and considering there's still the '\0', printf doesn't show the second string.
With (++s) you increment first and return the new value so you can stop at the end of the first string ,pay attention when you're first string has no characters you should deal with it in a separate case.

Comment: So, if the asker fixes this, will they solve the stack corruption issue? I'd say no. BTW, recommending to split your answer into multiple paragraphs, to make it easier to read.

Comment: thank you. got it. as you said, i tried to do it. The first loop is ok when i use `*(++s)`.           but as the above people said, i didn't realize the array isn't dynamic.